# "Looping" in Prolog by replacing goals with `fail`

Tags: prolog

In the following code:

```
bestof(Val, GT, Goal) :-
   retract(queue(WorstVal)),
   call(Goal),
   greater(GT, WorstVal, Val, GTVal),
   assertz(queue(GTVal)),
   fail;
   retract(queue(WorstVal)),
   Val = WorstVal.
```

I see in the debugger (LPA Prolog) that after `fail`ing, it executes `call(Goal)`. Why?

I might assume that it's because it's the last predicate that makes unification, but that doesn't explain the behaviour I see in the solution that's working for me (described later).

How can I make `fail` return to the beginning of the predicate?

The solution I found was to move the `retract(queue...` inside to `greater` predicate. It's working, but I don't understand what's going on here.

Bottom line - how Prolog chooses where to go back after `fail`ing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to retry from the nearest previous subgoal that produced a *choice point* when it succeeded. Unfortunately, this is one of the most interesting and different things about Prolog, so it isn't a simple answer.

After the `fail`, Prolog must begin backing up the calls that preceded the fail. In this case, the immediately preceding thing is `assertz(queue(GTVal))`. Prolog will undo that as it walks back, but it won't attempt to retry it because that is a *deterministic* predicate: it only produces one solution, so there's no reason to retry it. It then goes back to `greater(GT, WorstVal, Val, GTVal)`. I don't have the code in front of me to tell you why, but the behavior you're seeing tells me this is also a deterministic predicate, so no choice points are left on the stack for Prolog to retry here. If any bindings were established, Prolog will eliminate those and then go back to `call(Goal)`. Note that establishing bindings by itself does not make a choice point appear. There must be remaining choices.

`call(Goal)` is an interesting one, because it will depend on what `Goal` is whether this is deterministic or not. `call(true)` for instance, is deterministic, but `call(member(X, [1,2]))` is not. The behavior that you're seeing indicates that it is not. You can always get semideterministic behavior (one success or a failure) by wrapping your goal with `once/1`, as in `once(call(Goal))`. This is the easiest and safest way to introduce cuts into your program; the more general mechanism is with the `!` operator.